# Can you use variables within the "Schedule" task within a .yml file (Azure DevOps)

Tags: azure, yaml, devops

I'm trying to use a variable yaml file where I store a variable that is the cron syntax for a build. I wish to use this variable for multiple build pipelines, and want to be able to change the time/day of the build without having to go into each pipeline and change each schedule within each yaml pipeline.

However, trying this current method hits an error:

```
variable.yml
variables:
- name: cronSyntax
  value: "0 9 * * *"

azure-pipelines.yml

variables:
- template: variable.yml

schedules:
cron: ${{ cronSyntax }}
etc
```

I have also tried doing `$(cronSyntax)` but neither seem to work. Is it just a case that I cannot use variables within the schedule task in yaml? Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can't use pipeline variables when specifying schedules.

See the official documentation here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scheduled-triggers

[image]

Comment: Wow - I've been on this page and didn't see this. I'll read the documentation for stuff more carefully next time - thank you!